# Google custom search returning 403

Tags: google-api

I am looking for "Director of IT" folks from a specific set of companies. For this, I have set up a custom google search engine to search linkedin's public data. It worked for few initial searches but thereafter started returning 403 (Forbidden).

Why could this be happening? Could it be because of the pattern of searches generated by the my (python) script - Director of IT XYZ (XYZ generated from a list of companies)?

I have setup payment etc and that is not a problem.